# I need to save records from a excel sheet1 to another excel sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save data from Excel form with multiple selection options to another excel sheet. As the user will press add record button these values will be added to another excel and the input excel will be cleared 
Gaspcore is the input sheet and Gapdata is where the columns data will be saved.

Unable to debug this code line given below and code is mentioned below-

```
gapscore.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
```

---

```
Sub AddGAP()

Dim gapscore As Worksheet
Dim gapdata As Worksheet

Dim nextRow As Long
Dim oCol As Long

Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCopy As String
Dim myCell As Range

'cells to copy from Gapscore Sheet - some contain formulas
      myCopy = "G6:G161,N6:N161,O6:O161,Q6:Q161,R6:R161,S6:S161,T6:T161,U6:U161,V6:V161,X6:X161"

Set gapscore = Worksheets("Gap Analysis Score")
Set gapdata = Worksheets("GAPData")

     With gapdata
     nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
     End With

     With gapscore
     set myRng = .Range(myCopy)
     End With

    With gapdata
    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
    gapscore.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
    oCol = oCol + 1
    Next myCell
    End With

'clear input cells that contain constants
    With gapscore
   On Error Resume Next
   With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        .ClearContents
         Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
         End With
      On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: On the first iteration, `oCol` is `0`. There is no column 0.

Comment: Is this the reason why I am getting debug error on line - gapscore.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value 
 Could you let me know what needs to change in this code to make it run? I also have a small modification instead of cell ranges, I have input individual cells such as 'cells to copy from Gapscore Sheet - some contain formulas
myCopy = "A2 ,C3 ,G2 ,G6 ,K6 ,L6 ,M6 ,N6 ,O6 ,R6 ,S6 ,T6 ,V6 ,X6 ,Y6" Will this make a difference?

Comment: Yes - because `Cells(somenumber, 0)` is not valid. Move `oCol = oCol + 1` before that line.

Comment: Made the above change still getting the same debug error

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Please - explain *what* the error message is. Go ahead and [edit] your question with the new code you're trying too. Otherwise, it is very hard to help you, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ben, It does work with that fix, but it is saving the data in the same excel sheet not in the gapdata sheet.

Comment: That's because you're referencing the `gapscore` sheet: `gapscore.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value`. Your `With gapdata...End With` isn't actually referenced by any of the lines within it.

Comment: so in the above comment i should replace, gapscore with gap data?

Comment: Not sure exactly how you want the setup to be on the gapdata sheet, but yes it sounds like that's what you want.

Comment: It does work but it is saving all rows in a single row, does not take the next line of the column as a table eg: -

Comment: It does work but it is saving all data in a single row, does not take the next line of the column like a table eg: Row1-Data1-Data2-Data3 and then Row2-Data1-Data2-Data3

Comment: That's because you never increment `nextRow`.